# Android FingerprintManager CryptoObject Cipher init Private Key after biometric authenticate can use once only

Tags: android

I have a question to ask you guys as below.

Using FingerprintManager passing crytoObject type is Cipher.

The cipher I have init with a privateKey in decryption mode.

The privateKey is generated from AndroidKeystore with setUserAuthenticationRequired (true).

So, this private key will be used in cipher like cipher.init(DecryptionMode, privatekey), passing this cipher in Fingerprintmanager.authenticate.

After user verify I can successfully use the cryptoobject result, successfully get the cipher and do decryption (doFinal) in an encrypted String.

After done decrypt the string, I have to proceed signature because I need to use same private key second time for signature and get a complete string.

Here is the problem, it will always throw exception user not authenticated, is that mean cryptoObject result return from FingerprintManager after successfully verified the fingerprint its cipher type object can use for once only ? I can use it once for dofinal decrypt an encrypted string and after that I have to use the same private key for signature it will hit user not authenticated exception.

Does it mean user need to verify biometric again? It can only be used 1 time after user successfully verify, the cipher which I done init(decrypt mode , private key) it return and cannot use twice. I already tested setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds (int seconds) this will always hit not authenticated and I didnt use setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds .

Please I need expert help on fingerprintManager (cryptoObject result) when authenticate successful, the cipher type with privateKey can only use one time. I need to continue use it second time without hitting user not authenticated. Please.

setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds this is not working.

cipher init PrivateKey and pass into fingerprintManager.authenticate(cryptoObject)

When fingerprint successfully verified, the cipher can be used one time only. If need to use the same private key in signature it will hit user not authenticated. How to make the private key available ?

Comment: See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder): _"Cryptographic operations involving keys which are authorized to be used for a duration of time after a successful user authentication event can only use secure lock screen authentication"_. What you're trying to do (combine a non-zero ValidityDuration with calling the `FingerprintManager` directly) isn't supported. You'll have to use the `KeyguardManager` as described in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of there being two "types" of keys: per-use keys, meaning authentication must take place for every use of the key, and time-based keys, which are available for an app-specified time after authentication.

Both types of keys are created with `setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)`, but with different time parameters in `setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(t)`. Per-use keys `(t == -1)` can only be unlocked by biometrics, whereas time-based keys `(t > 0)` can be unlocked by biometrics or pin/pattern/password.

- Biometric only

  - Create key using `t = -1` (default)
  - Unlock using `BiometricPrompt#authenticate(CryptoObject)`
- Password or biometric

  - Create key using `t > 0`
  - Unlock using lockscreen, or `BiometricPrompt` with `setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)`

You can see the sample [androidx.biometric](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/biometric) app [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/samples/BiometricDemos/src/main/java/com/example/android/biometric), which implements both use cases.